# VBA: Copying a row, inserting it above with one cell's value changed

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to find a way to copy the values of an identified row and insert it above with the same values except for one column. If possible, it would be great to find a way to change 2 cells in the identified row too. I'm completely new in trying to use VBA so I haven't gotten very far... currently I can insert a blank row, but with no contents. Hopefully to make it clearer, here are the steps I'm trying to complete.

1. In column C, work through each row and identify/action each one that contains "ITEM1_ITEM2"
2. Insert row above (or below?) the identified row containing all the same values, except for column C, which has the value changed to "ITEM2", and column H, which has its number value halved.
3. The identified row has its column C value changed to "ITEM1" and its column H value is halved as well.
4. Move on to the next identified row with "ITEM1_ITEM2" and complete the same.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't even need to complete all the steps... even just figuring out how to just copy/paste the cells in inserted row would help. Thanks!

```
Public Sub sortICs()

    Dim bottom As Long, top As Long
    Dim row As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        top = 1
        bottom = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
            
        For row = bottom To top Step -1
            If .Range("C" & row).Value = "ITEM1_ITEM2" Then
                .Range("C" & row).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        Next row
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro of copying a row and inserting? That will give you the basic syntax. If you are copying above I would loop forwards not backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```vb
Public Sub sortICs()

    Dim bottom As Long, top As Long
    Dim rw As Range, newRow As Range, x, i As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1  'work backwards so you don't interfere when inserting rows
            Set rw = .Rows(i)
            If rw.Columns("C").Value = "ITEM1_ITEM2" Then
                rw.Offset(1, 0).Insert
                Set newRow = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'the just-inserted row
                rw.Copy newRow
                
                rw.Columns("C").Value = "ITEM1"
                newRow.Columns("C").Value = "ITEM2"
                
                x = rw.Columns("H").Value / 2
                rw.Columns("H").Value = x
                newRow.Columns("H").Value = x
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```